# C program to display the integer that only occurs only once

Tags: c

So I need to do C program that asks 20 integers from user (number between 10-100) and print only the numbers that occurs only once.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  int i=20;
  
  while(i-- && n <100 && n>10) 
  { 
    scanf("%d", &n); 
  } 

  printf("Number is not between 10-100. Try again");
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think is the value of `n` the first time code executes `n <100`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the numbers in the array and check for repetitions.

Here you have a naive implementation (you can improve many things). Instead of user input I fill the array with random (pseudo random) numbers

```
void printDistinct(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    for(size_t cnum = 0; cnum < size; cnum++)
    {
        int isDistinct = 1;
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
            if(index != cnum)
                if(arr[cnum] == arr[index])
                {
                    isDistinct = 0;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(isDistinct)
            printf("arr[%zu] = %d\n", cnum, arr[cnum]);
    }
}

#define NNUM    50

int main(void)
{
    int arr[NNUM];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < NNUM; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 50;
    }
    printDistinct(arr, NNUM);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7a9ejfrav